# Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2

Tags: android, react-native, androidx

I am moving to androidX but I receive:

```
Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.
Required by:
    project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.60.4
```

My project gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       ...
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like I am missing another source. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

AndroidX dependencies are available in [Google's Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com), which you haven't added under `allprojects` -> `repositories` in your project `build.gradle`.

Insert `google()` in `allprojects` -> `repositories` before everything else.
You can also replace `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` with `google()` in `buildscript` -> `repositories`.

So it should look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Sync your project after making these changes and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

From ReactNative version **0.60**, it supports **AndroidX**. So you need to add AndroidX dependency also.

Add below dependency into your **app/build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
}
```

Make sure that you have added this line in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Comment: I included it but the message stays the same

Comment: I updated my answer. If it still doesn't help much then check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56721262/9199362